# Change from iframe to Popup window

Tags: jquery, iframe

On click on any ( .sce_edit_link_a, .sce_edit_link_short, .sce_image_link, .sce_file_link ) of these links it will show their content inside an Iframe using

```
link = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#sce_frame').attr('src', link);
```

Is there anyway to show them in a popup window rather an iframe?

```
<!--V.0.7-->
<div class="sce_hidden">
    <div id="edit_mode">
        <iframe src="#" style="width:100%; height:100%;" frameborder="0" name="sce_frame" id="sce_frame" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sce_edit_link_a, .sce_edit_link_short, .sce_image_link, .sce_file_link').click(function(){
        link = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#sce_frame').attr('src', link);

        $( '#edit_mode' ).dialog({
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            resizable: true,
            buttons: [{
                text: '<?php echo(lang_front_close); ?>',
                click: function(){ $(this).dialog('close'); window.location.reload();}
            }]
        });

        return false;
    });

    $('#sce_controlcenter').click(function(){
        link = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#sce_frame').attr('src', link);

        $( '#edit_mode' ).dialog({
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            resizable: true,
            buttons: [{
                text: '<?php echo(lang_front_close); ?>',
                click: function(){ $(this).dialog('close'); window.location.reload();}
            }]
        });

        return false;
    });

    $('#sce_reloadpage').click(function(){
        window.location.reload();
        return false;
    });
});

<?php
if($_GET['reload']=='yes'){
    echo('window.location.href = \'//'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'\';');
}
?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `window.open` instead of setting the iframe src

```
link = $(this).attr('href');
window.open(link,"windowName","resizable,scrollbars,status");
```

[window.open MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open)

Comment: I tried that before and it did not work, it opened it in a new window rather a popup, and some functions stopped working, for a live preview go to: http://codysilverkin.com/editor and login using admin and pass then click on Edit Contnet

Comment: do you mean it opened in a new tab? if it opens a new window that is what a popup is, unless you mean an in page popup like a modal box